When Is It Okay to Leave Mediocre Work Off Of Your CV?
I'm currently a first-year PhD student in a quantitative science. As an undergraduate I performed research with a postdoc which resulted in a co-authored paper on arXiv. To fulfill a requirement to receive honors with my degree, I also wrote a senior thesis based on the work. My department explicitly said we were allowed to incorporate past papers into the senior thesis as long as we cited them and clearly marked what material was adapted, so most of my senior thesis is just copied from the paper.
But I also had to write some introductory material to make the thesis accessible to non-specialists in the field, and to be honest I don't think I did a very good job writing it. I did this kind of quickly and wasn't very motivated because I didn't expect that anybody would ever actually read it.
If somebody in the future wants to know what I worked on in undergrad, I would much rather that they look at the co-authored paper rather than the thesis, which is just the co-authored paper with some poorly, hastily-written pedagogical material tacked onto the beginning. Would it be considered dishonest to leave the senior thesis off of my CV and ORCID page?

Anecdotally, I have hardly ever seen an undergraduate thesis listed on a CV of someone more than a couple years into graduate study.

You need not worry, one should not be listing their undergraduate thesis on their CV anyway. In terms of "products of research" one should list Publications (peer reviewed), Book Chapters, Conferences (peer reviewed), Conferences (non-peer reviewed). An undergraduate thesis is just a glorified assignment, nobody will dig it up or hold it against you.

In general one need not list everything on their CV. In fact, for some it would make an impossibly long document. What you include should be valuable to you and to others, but it is fine to leave off early work (especially).
It is unlikely that people will be much interested in your undergrad work once you begin doctoral study. For most purposes it isn't relevant. And none of us are experts at those earliest stages.
But others may not judge it as harshly as you do, if they know it was done early on.
